# How to use numpy.void type

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I loaded a MATLAB `.mat` file via `scipy.io.loadmat` and it gave me a list of `numpy.void` objects.

What are they, how can they be used and where can I get some reference **documentation** on them?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

According to the `numpy` documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html, `numpy.void` types are defined as **flexible** data types.  Basically, these are data types where there is no pre-defined type associated to the variable(s) you're looking at.  If you look at `numpy`, you have data types such as `float`, `uint8`, `bool`, `string`, etc.

`void` is to accommodate for more generic and flexible types and are for those data types that don't necessary fall into any one of these pre-defined data types.  This situation is mostly encountered when you're loading in a `struct` where each element has multiple data types associated with multiple fields.  Each structure element could have a combination of different data types, and the amalgamation of all of these data types to represent an instance of this structure element thus leads us to `numpy.void`.

With the documentation, you can certainly do the same operations like you would with any other data type.  Take a look at the `generic` data type methods here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.generic.html#numpy.generic .  In fact, all `numpy` data types are derived from this generic class, including `numpy.void`.

In the first link I provided at the beginning of this post, it shows a good example of how to create a custom record type, where a record is a combination of a tuple of numbers and a string.  When creating a list of these records, each type in the list is of type `numpy.void` and it demonstrates that a record is of this data type.  However, bear in mind that this record list has a data type **that is of this record**, but each element of this list **will be of type `numpy.void`**.

---

However, as a matter of self-containment, let's re-create the example here:  Let's create a custom record type where it has two fields associated for each variable you create:

- A 16-bit string with a field named `name`
- A 2-element tuple of floating point numbers that are 64-bits each, with a field named `grades`

As such, you'd do something like:

```
import numpy as np
dt = np.dtype([('name', np.str_, 16), ('grades', np.float64, (2,))])
```

As such, let's create an example list of two elements and instantiate their fields:

```
x = np.array([('Sarah', (8.0, 7.0)), ('John', (6.0, 7.0))], dtype=dt)
```

Because we made this list into a `numpy.array`, we expect its data type to be so:

```
type(x)
```

We get:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Remember, the list itself is a `numpy.array`, but **not** the individual elements.

---

To access the second element of this list, which is the second record, we do:

```
x[1]
```

We get:

```
('John', [6.0, 7.0])
```

To check the type of the second record, we do:

```
type(x[1])
```

We get:

```
<type 'numpy.void'> # As expected
```

---

## Some additional bonuses for you

To access the name of the second record, we do:

```
x[1]['name']
```

We get:

```
'John'
```

To access the grades of the second record, we do:

```
x[1]['grades']
```

We get:

```
array([ 6.,  7.])
```

To check the type of the name inside the second record, we do:

```
type(x[1]['name'])
```

We get:

```
<type 'numpy.string_'>
```

To check the type of the grades inside the second record, we do:

```
type(x[1]['grades'])
```

We get:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

---

Take note that each element in this list is of type `numpy.void`.  However, the individual fields for each element in our list is either a tuple of numbers, or a string.  The **collection** of these elements together is of type `numpy.void`.

Comment: Your description of flexible dtypes is misleading. Flexible simply means that `itemsize` varies. A `str_` is also a flexible dtype.

Comment: Furthermore, there's a second type of `np.void` that doesn't have any `.names` - which is just a chunk of raw memory (bytes, but not `np.bytes_` which is null-terminated) - so `np.array([b'123'], np.void)` is valid

Comment: I have loaded a dataset with objects of type 'np.void' that does not containt the .names attribute. How can I discover the names of this 'np.void' element?

Comment: @ThaNoob ```myvoidarray.dtype.names``` worked for me